# How to fix 'AssertionError: all exprs should be Column'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I am receiving 'AssertionError: all exprs should be Column' error.
Being a newbee to Pyspark and Pandas, I am not sure where it is going wrong.
This is the piece of code which is throwing that error.

```
new = data.groupby(['PERIOD_ID', 'STORE_ID']).agg(lambda MKT: '_DUPLICATE_'.join(MKT)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Im not sure, if you can use Lambdas here as you wish. In general, there are built-in aggregation functions for "group by's". If you want to use your own aggregation function you need to make an udaf first. Before that, I would do everything to avoid it, because you could run into heavy performance trouble.
Maybe you should give a little more context to your question, then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Here you can find all pyspark functions for grouped Data. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData

Comment: Oh, yes. You cant write a lambda in agg() for  a pyspark df. I converted it into a Pandas DF and it worked. Thanks.